# Dispatcher failed to deliver Message (Spring Integration)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I'm developing my first flow app with Spring Integration. Shortly, my goal is to obtain files json from a tar.gz. I finished and it work well but at the end, the gateway send an exception instead to end.

The context is this:

```
<int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="0" />

<int:gateway id="extractedFolderProcess" default-reply-channel="endFlow"
    default-request-channel="inputChannelDatasetPath"
    error-channel="error_channel"
    service-interface="com.javarticles.spring.integration.utilities.ExtractedFolderProcess">
</int:gateway>

<int:channel id="error_channel"/>

<int:filter id="nullMessage" input-channel="error_channel" ref="errorFlow" />


<int:channel id="inputChannelDatasetPath"/>

<int:channel id="endFlow" />

<int:channel id="filesIn" >
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="jsonChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="extractedJsonChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="2" />

<int:splitter id="unzipSplitter" input-channel="inputChannelDatasetPath"  ref="unziperDataset" output-channel="filesIn"/>

<int:splitter id="testSplitter" input-channel="filesIn" ref="jsonSplitter" output-channel="jsonChannel">
    <int:poller task-executor="executor" fixed-delay="1000" /> 
</int:splitter>

<int:aggregator input-channel="jsonChannel" ref="jsonAggregator" output-channel="extractedJsonChannel" method="add"/>

<int:aggregator input-channel="extractedJsonChannel" 
ref="sumAggregator" output-channel="endFlow"    
method="add"
release-strategy="releaseStrategySumAggregator" 
correlation-strategy="correlationIdStrategySumAggregator" />

<bean id="errorFlow" class="com.javarticles.spring.integration.endPoints.ErrorFlow" />
<bean id="releaseStrategySumAggregator" class="com.javarticles.spring.integration.utilities.ReleaseStrategySumAggregator" />
<bean id="correlationIdStrategySumAggregator" class="com.javarticles.spring.integration.utilities.CorrelationIdStrategySumAggregator" />
<bean id="jsonSplitter" class="com.javarticles.spring.integration.endPoints.JsonSplitter" />
<bean id="unziperDataset" class="com.javarticles.spring.integration.endPoints.UnzipDataset" />
<bean id="jsonAggregator" class="com.javarticles.spring.integration.endPoints.JsonAggregator"/>
<bean id="sumAggregator" class="com.javarticles.spring.integration.endPoints.SumAggregator" />
```

and stackstrace shows this:

```
2018-09-10 14:28:36 ERROR LoggingHandler:192 - org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=15878, headers={sequenceNumber=5875, correlationId=0, check=0, id=06f00498-e3ea-2dd0-e5e0-5663974e0e45, sequenceSize=5875, timestamp=1536582516348}]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.wrapExceptionIfNecessary(AbstractDispatcher.java:133)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:120)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.completeGroup(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:671)
at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:418)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.handleMessage(PollingConsumer.java:129)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:287)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
... 33 more
```

Probably the message sended by second Aggregator has a bad headers, but I'm not sure. How can I resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your configuration. 
Your `filesIn`, `jsonChannel`, `extractedJsonChannel` are all pollable channels, however, the only polling consumer I see is `testSplitter`. So I don't really see how any of the aggregators getting messages.

I would suggest to change those channels to DirectChannels (remove `<queue>`) as a starting point.

Comment: May we see more stack trace? Looks like you are losing important headers in between...

Comment: Yes, I 'll add it into the question.

Comment: Ok. Isn’t helpful, but as I said before you lose `replyChannel` and `errorChannel` headers in between. I somehow think it is about your Aggregator and that `add()` functionality, but this is going to be a speculative. Let’s turn on debug logging for Spring Integration package and let’s see in logs after which step you don’t have those headers any more! After finding you need to ensure headers presence using `MessageBuilder` and its `copyHeaders()` from a the request message

Comment: Ok, resolved. Thanks. The problem was that I lost errorChannel and replyChannel in the messages after their custom creation.